# Worker crashing for a JSON post request in WCF

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, backgroundworker, application-pool

I have WCF service which takes a post request and JSON. The service then use the C# backgroundworker class to further parse JSON and update DB.

But when I post JSON that is larger than 7KB, the worker is crashing. I am not getting any exceptions or errors in the application logs, but when I look at system logs , I get this,

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WAS" Guid="{524B5D04-133C-4A62-8362-64E8EDB9CE40}"    EventSourceName="WAS" /> 
<EventID Qualifiers="32768">5011</EventID> 
<Version>0</Version> 
<Level>3</Level> 
<Task>0</Task> 
<Opcode>0</Opcode> 
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-06-16T18:51:21.000000000Z" /> 
<EventRecordID>74571</EventRecordID> 
<Correlation /> 
<Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" /> 
<Channel>System</Channel> 
<Computer>xxxxx</Computer> 
<Security /> 
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="AppPoolID">YYYYYYYY</Data> 
<Data Name="ProcessID">ZZZZZZZ</Data> 
<Binary>6D000780</Binary> 
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Could this be a memory leak? How can I find the exact cause if my application log does not show any errors?

PS: The service is working perfect in local and staging environments we have. But live server has a different configuration.

Comment: `live server has a different configuration.` - can you paste the wcf binding config here? how is it different to local and staging environments? do those environments handle inputs larger than 7kb OK ?

Comment: The web.config is the same in both environments. The difference is in staging the app uses default application pool and the live wcf service has it own application pool. Also staging can handle JSON files up to 1 MB.

Comment: you still have not posted your WCF bindings - this may be crucial - see http://fczaja.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/wcf-how-to-increase-allowed-request.html

Comment: @wal that post helped. The culprit was   maxStringContentLength in readerquotas. I increased binding parameters one by one and increasing maxStringContentLength fixed. I still don't know what prevented the code from logging the exceptions.  There should be a system exception raised in case of "The maximum string content length quota exceeded". Thank you very much for pointing me on right direction.

Comment: glad you have solved this. welcome to the world of bad WCF error messages. you did however say it worked on staging - did that have a different `maxStringContentLength` setting?

Comment: nope.  maxStringContentLength was not set in staging. So I assume it was set to the default.